# Prevent scrolling with empty href

Tags: html, css

We are developing application on our iOS,

Inside our html page, there is "Email Results" button. when I click on the button the screen scrolls up immediately.

HTML:

```
<div class="result-button-wrapper"> 
    <a target="_blank" href="" class="button button-email"><span class="icon"></span>Email Results</a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
display:inline-block;
padding:12px;
position:relative;
margin:12px;

cursor:pointer;

color:#fff !important;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 1px 2px #222222;
text-align:center;}

.button.button-email {
    display:block;
    width:130px;
    padding-left:28px;
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;}
```

if I removed the "button" from the class like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="" class="button-email"><span class="icon"></span>Email Results</a>
```

, the button works and I can click it

Where is the issue in my CSS.

Comment: You might have better results using an actual `button` element. It makes more sense syntactically, and browsers treat them differently than an `a` element.

Answer (score 4):

1. I notice the class `.button` does not have a closing bracket. You may want to fix this.
2. Toggle with the presences of # in the href value. That is href="#". Do not remove "button" from the class when doing this.

EDITED

Using JavaScript, apply `javascript:void(0)` as the `href` value.

**Example**

`<div class="result-button-wrapper"> 
    <a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button button-email">
        <span class="icon"></span>Email Results
    </a> 
</div>`

Alternatively, you can use jQuery

```
$('a.button-email').click(function (event) { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry missed the closing bracket, it is existed in the code. I have added the "#" in href, but the issue still exist. the same code works on iPad and Android. but not iPhone. The time I touch the button on iPhone the page scroll to the top.